# Detecting flight info via NSDataDetector's NSTextCheckingTypeTransitInformation is not ever matching anything

Tags: ios, objective-c, datadetectortypes, nsdatadetector

Has anyone had any luck using NSDataDetector on iOS to match flight information?  It looks really [amazingly powerful](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSDataDetector_Class/Reference/Reference.html), except I can't get it to work at all.

Here's what I'm trying:

```
NSDataDetector *detector = [NSDataDetector dataDetectorWithTypes:(NSTextCheckingTypes)NSTextCheckingTypeTransitInformation error:&error];

[detector enumerateMatchesInString:string
                           options:0
                             range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])
                        usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *result, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop) {

                            NSLog(@"Detected: %@, %@", result, [result URL]);
}
```

I'm trying this on a variety of strings, including the body of every calendar entry I could find in my calendar that had flight info in it.

Examples:

- "UA460 SFO to YVR [Flight] 6/12/2013 United Airlines(UA) #460 dep SFO 7:57pm PDT arr YVR 10:14pm PDT;  Ticket #0162360127882, Ticket #0162360127883; conf #K5XBXY; Note:, Seats:---/30A , Seats:---/30B 
  "
- "Pick up Laura at Airport  UA 1255"
- "Lufthansa 1128 Business (C) | Seat 07F Frankfurt Barcelona 2 h 0 m 679miles
  FRA 1:15pm BCN 3:15pm , Arrives on Fri Oct/5/2012
  Lufthansa 1128
  Business (C) | Seat 07F | Confirm or change seats with the airline*"

But none of these match.  If I change data detector types to include NSTextCheckingTypePhoneNumber or NSTextCheckingTypeLink, those match great. But I can't get flight data.

Any one have any luck with this?

Comment: Do you have any updates on this?

Answer (score 0):

Flight numbers are detected on OS X, but not on iOS. Please file a bug with Apple to either get the documentation updated, or to get support for this on iOS.

Answer (score 0):

```
    NSDataDetector *detector = [NSDataDetector dataDetectorWithTypes:(NSTextCheckingTypes)NSTextCheckingTypeTransitInformation error:nil];
    NSString *result = @"Pick up Laura at Airport UA 1255";
    [detector enumerateMatchesInString:result options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [result length]) usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult * _Nullable result, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
        NSLog(@"%@ %@",result, [result components]);
    }];


2016-05-20 11:49:29.912 detectTest[20894:4085484] <NSTransitInformationCheckingResult: 0x7fcc92019f30>{25, 7} {
    Flight = 1255;
}
```

the only difference is flight info stored in `[result components]` rather than `[result URL]`